# jammy does not reproduce 2.7K and beyond

Tags: 22.04, video

I have a Dell Inspiron 5559 laptop with

- 8GB of memory
- Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
- HAINAN graphics (, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 2.50, 6.2.0-26-generic) / Mesa Intel ® HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2) Wayland graphics system.

The machine is dual booted with Windows 10.

I tried playing GoPro11 clips at 5.3K, 4K, 2.7K, and 1080p. Both using "Video" and using VLC, only 1080p is reproduced — in all other tested formats, the initial still image appears (the audio is heard perfectly) or at most with a few gray frames. With Windows 10 all movies are seen perfectly (even 5.3K) both with VLC and with the standard player.

How can I fix it since I would like to always use Ubuntu (since 2007 I use win only when I have no alternative).